# Azure Databricks Delta table Access through API

Tags: c#, azure-databricks, azure-api-management, azure-synapse, delta-lake

There is a requirement to expose data present in Azure Databricks delta tables through Rest API. These API will be used by both internal & external users.

Query:

What are the best possible option available to expose delta table data through Rest API end point.

I'll be using C# to develop the API and use Azure API management service to handle all the aspects of security, monitoring & logging.

Please guide what best strategy to use to develop this API layer.

Thanks,

Comment: hi @user1941025, there is no proper way C# to develop the REST API in azure DataBricks.

Comment: any other framework/tools  to support this requirement, please let me know

Comment: yes, you use python. for more refer this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/python-api)